# How to stop all comsumers with BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I'm trying to develop a Producer-Consumer system, where the producer insert files into the blockingqueue, and the consumer take the files and process them.

I want to create an option to stop and resume the system (stop all comsumer threads).

*Summerry:*

1. The user click on "stop" button whice calls the stop() Function at MyProgram.java.
2. Every consumer thread will check if is running process is alive and kill the process. After change the consumer while to false.
3. I got all that following exceptions (java.lang.InterruptedException)

** I attached a pseudo code of my classes.
What am i doing wrong ?

**Error - From every consumer thread**

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
Mar 21, 2018 6:43:15 PM Consumer run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
    at Consumer.run(Consumer.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 21, 2018 6:43:15 PM Consumer run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
    at Consumer.run(Consumer.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Consumer**

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue<File> queue = null;
    private volatile Boolean threadRunning = true;
    private File originalFile;

    public void run() {
        while (threadRunning) {
            try {
                originalFile = queue.take();
                tempFile = new File(tempPath.toString() + "\\" + originalFile.getName());;
                try {
                    process = getProcessBuilder(tempFile).start();
                    process.waitFor();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        threadRunning = false;
        if (process != null && process.isAlive()) {
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer**

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

    protected BlockingQueue<File> queue = null;
    private volatile boolean running;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
        running=true;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Producer Started");
        try {
            while (running) {
            // Adding files to Queue ........
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**MyProgram Class**

```
public class MyProgram {

    private ExecutorService service;
    private Vector<Consumer> listOfThreads;

    private TaskParameters task;

    private Producer producer;

    public MyProgram(String taskDirPath, String taskName) {
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        createAndExecuteThreads();
    }

    private void createAndExecuteThreads() {

        BlockingQueue<File> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(100);
        producer = new Producer(queue);
        new Thread(producer).start();
        service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < task.getNumOfThreads(); ++i) {
            listOfThreads.add(new Consumer(queue, "Consumer " + (i + 1)));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfThreads.size(); ++i) {
            service.submit(listOfThreads.get(i));
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }

    public void stop() {
        Running = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfThreads.size(); i++) {
            listOfThreads.get(i).stop();
        }
        service.shutdownNow();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all your trade are waiting on `queue.take()` call, your method may work if you if you are sure the queue is always filled ...

Otherwise a better way to stop everything way will be to

- the provider empty the queue and start to filing it with X fake files, for example a file named stop.stop (X is the number of consumers threads)
- the consumer detect the fake file and put his own threadRunning to false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw the solution "poison pill" you are talking about, and it's really nice solution. But I dio not think it solves my problem, because I want to "kill" the running process immediately. And to my understanding, the consumer will finish working on the process, and only then will he stop pulling files. No ?